# Manipulating list order

Tags: python

I am an artist taking a class on how to manipulate code to make poetry. Python was not supposed to be a prerequisite, but I am not getting it! Please help- we are supposed to make a snowball poem.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
my_string = "you're going home in a Chelsea ambulance"

counter = 0

new_list = my_string.split()

def make_a_snowball (text):
    poem = ' '
    for i in text:
        poem = poem + "\n" + i 
    print (poem)

make_a_snowball (new_list)
```

The result is:

```
you're
going
home
etc..
```

I'd like it to look like:

```
you're
you're going
you're going home 
etc...
```

Any suggestions? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the print method inside the loop:

```
my_string = "you're going home in a Chelsea ambulance"

counter = 0

new_list = my_string.split()
print(new_list)

def make_a_snowball(text):
    poem = ' '
    for word in text:
        poem = poem + ' ' + word
        print(poem)


make_a_snowball(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    print(poem.join(new_list[:i]))
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)? This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From Review.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your whole poem be stored in one long string, here's how you'd do it:

```
def make_a_snowball(text):
    poem_line = ''
    full_poem = ''
    for word in text:
        poem_line += word + ' '
        full_poem += poem_line + '\n'
    print(full_poem)
    return full_poem
```

This prints exactly what you want, except all at once rather than line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code is printing each item on a new line is because we are inadvertantly adding a newline character between the terms, when we should be adding a space character.

In the following code, if we replace the `\n` with a `" "` and shift the `print()` function inwards so that it prints every time we loop through the items of the list, then this should work just fine.

```
my_string = "you're going home in a Chelsea ambulance"

counter = 0

new_list = my_string.split()

def make_a_snowball (text):
    poem = ' '
    for i in text:
        poem = poem + " " + i 
        print (poem)

make_a_snowball (new_list)
```

This results in:

```
you're
you're going
you're going home
you're going home in
you're going home in a
you're going home in a Chelsea
you're going home in a Chelsea ambulance
```

A couple of additional thoughts.
In your code above, a `counter` is not necessary.

I like my code to be somewhat self descriptive, so I might replace this:

```
for i in text:
    poem = poem + " " + i 
    print (poem)
```

with

```
for word in text:
    poem = poem + " " + word 
    print (poem)
```